# How to impersonate current outlook user in outlook addin (.NET Code)

Tags: .net, outlook-addin, impersonation, exchangewebservices

I am having a .net based outlook addin that will communicate exchange web service using stored credentials (user name and  current password). Now i wanna remove this dependacy and impersonate current outlook user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the current username from Outlook. Unless the user signed in to Outlook using Windows Authentication, in this case you can simply use CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.

Why are you using EWS to communicate with Exchange? Instead you could use the Outlook object model.